# How to get the dot in my email to appear in "send mail as"?

Tags: gmail, email, alias

I don't have a dot in my email but I signed up an Amazon/Audible account with a dot in it. Now I am trying to get a refund but they need the email to be sent from the email address with a dot. I went to settings and added the email with a dot in it with "alias" checked but when I send a message to a dummy account, the dot still doesn't appear.

Answer (score 7):

I also had a similar problem with them and found although you own these addresses you would have to add them individually to be able to send a reply. I couldn't find no instructions to do this but I managed to figure it out by:

- Logging in to Gmail via my desktop/computer
- Click on settings (gear icon)
- Accounts and imports setting
- Scroll to section 'send email as'
- Click on add email address

  - Input the email with the .
  - Make sure the treat as alias is checked
  - Click next steps
- Make the . email your default
- Then click on always reply from default address

That should solve your problem. Once you set this up you you can alternate which email you want it to be sent from when composing or replying.

Answer (score -2):

> ### Dots don't matter in Gmail addresses
>
> If someone accidentally adds dots to your address when emailing you,
> you'll still get that email. For example, if your email is
> johnsmith@gmail.com, you own all dotted versions of your address:
>
> - john.smith@gmail.com
> - jo.hn.sm.ith@gmail.com
> - j.o.h.n.s.m.i.t.h@gmail.com
>
> **Note:** If you use Gmail through work,
> school, or other organization (like yourdomain.com or yourschool.edu),
> dots do change your address. To change the dots in your username,
> contact your admin.
>
> **https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7436150?hl=en**

I guess that would be the same reason why you can't set up a doted address to be shown in the received email.